# Javascript/regex: Remove text between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Would it be possible to change this:

```
Hello, this is Mike [example]
```

to this:

```
Hello, this is Mike
```

Using JS + Regex? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you prefer doing this using a regular expression, consider the following.

```
var r = 'Hello, this is Mike [example]'.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/, '');
console.log(r); //=> "Hello, this is Mike"
```

If your data contains more text in brackets you want removed, use the `g` (global) modifier.

Based off your given string, you could just use split here.

```
var r = 'Hello, this is Mike [example]'.split(' [')[0]
console.log(r); //=> "Hello, this is Mike"
```

Comment: `.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/g, '');` is what most people are looking for. Your example only removes 1 set of [], adding `/g` will remove all occurances.

Answer (score 4):

My first thought would be:

```
"Hello, this is Mike [example]".replace(/(\[.+\])/g, '');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zs390omL/1/).

Or, as noted in the comments:

```
"Hello, this is Mike [example]".replace(/(\[.*?\])/g, '');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zs390omL/2/).

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I'd use `/\[.*?\]/g` instead; `+` is greedy, and would break something like `Hello [something], this is Mike [something else]`, turning it into `Hello'. `*?` would only take characters until the closing `]`.

Comment: @Jacob Well, the expected outcome is not well defined. The language described in the problem isn't even regular. Hence regular expressions are not suitable.

Comment: Technically speaking the `]` does not need to be escaped. It would only need to escaped within a character class. Also, the grouping operators `()` are superfluous. I would remove the first part of your answer, since it could be considered wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Removal of the whitespace is not always desirable, e.g. when the brackets are used for some types of markup. Replace with a single space.

```
text = "This is a [big]large[/big] bear."
text = text.replace(/\s*\[.*?\]\s*/g, ' ')
```

result: text="This is a large bear."

Answer (score 0):

This example shows removing '<' & '>', escaping using a text node function,
removing divs and their content and finally removing '[' & ']'.

For a complete list of escape characters see:[mateam.net](https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/)

```
function escapeHTML(html) {
  return document.createElement('div').appendChild(document.createTextNode(html)).parentNode.innerHTML;
}

var a = document.createElement('div');
a.id = 'test';
a.innerHTML = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.onclick = function(){

var str = '<a href="ggoggle.ca">ggogle</a> wish i was here <img src="image"><div>another div</div> [square brackets] <div>yet another div</div>';

console.log('\n original string:\n'+str);

str = str.replace(/\<div\>.*?\<\/div\>/g,'');

console.log('\n removed divs & content:\n'+str);
// <a href="ggoggle.ca">ggogle</a> wish i was here <img src="image"> [square brackets]

var str = escapeHTML(str);

console.log('\n escape using text node - escapeHTML(html):\n'+str);
// &lt;a href="ggoggle.ca"&gt;ggogle&lt;/a&gt; wish i was here &lt;img src="image"&gt; [square brackets]

str = str.replace(/\<.*?\>/g,'').replace(/\&lt;.*?\&gt;/g,'');
    
console.log('\n removed \'< >\' and escaped (&lt; &gt;) and content:\n'+str);
// ggogle wish i was here  [square brackets] 

str = str.replace(/\[.*?\]/g,'')

console.log('\n remove square brackets and their content:\n'+str);
// ggogle wish i was here


}
```