# Need to replace numbers between [...] with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside a string: I need to replace the number between `[ ]` by another number with Javascript or jQuery.

What is the best way to proceed ?

Eamples

```
"[12345].Checked" > "[1].Checked"
"[123].RequestID" > "[21].RequestID"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You could try `.replace` with a regular expression?

Comment: You can also use indexOf but replace with regex will be better solution.

Comment: Yes but I am a clue with regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776973/javascript-regex-remove-text-between-square-brackets/25777116#25777116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function fixNum(str, newnum) {
     return str.replace(/\[\d+\]/,'[' + newnum + ']')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace`:

`"[12345].Checked".replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, "[1]") // "[1].Checked"`

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions:

```
/\[(\d+)\]/
```

It searches a number (no matter length) inside a `[]` set.

Combined with replace you can make it.

Test it:

https://regex101.com/r/zT5kD0/1

Comment: Your sample doesn't give the correct result

Comment: @freedomn-m are you serious? This is the correct regular expression. In fact, the other answers have the same regexp.

Comment: I didn't say the regex was wrong - I said your sample was wrong - the link - did you even bother to try it?   Using your sample, with test `[12345].Checked` and *substitution* of `1` (as per question) - what you you get?  *Not* `[1].Checked`.

Comment: You should substitute with `[1]`. Like the other answers. https://regex101.com/r/zT5kD0/2

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` method to replace the part

```
    function replaceStr(string,orgText,replaceText){
      var res = string.replace(orgText, replaceText);
      return res;
    }

console.log(replaceStr("[12345].Checked",'12345','1'));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/opdLgq77/)

Comment: Why introduce a function when `"[12345].Checked".replace('12345','1');` would be way shorter and is already a good enough solution?

Comment: making it more generalized.Beside "[12345].Checked" there is one more string to be replaced  "[123].RequestID" > "[21].RequestID"

Comment: Yes, but `replaceStr("[12345].Checked",'12345','1')` takes up more characters than just `"[12345].Checked".replace('12345','1');` AND you introduce a function that already has a function.